# Cannot create database/run other commands in DB2 Command Line Processor

Tags: database, db2

I'm unable to create database using DB2 Command Line Processor (DB2 Express C). I wrote a simple operation to create a database :

```
db2=> create database wiki
```

It's showing me an error :

> SQL1092N  The requested command or operation failed because the user
>   ID does not have the authority to perform the requested command or
>   operation.  User ID: "VINAYAKP".

I've never worked on DB2 before. Also, from  *First Steps*; it is just opening a prompt and it displays  nothing. I'm using a **thin client**. Kindly tell me about this error and how to resolve it. Also, **need to know any alternate way other than using the command line processor.**

*Note: I'm using Windows OS*

Thanks

Comment: Searching for the error code revealed ..?

Comment: @pst i'm new to db2. Couldnt find the root of this issue. i need to know what causes this error?

Comment: Now, search for `SQL1092N` and .. any leads?

Comment: @pst that is obvious. is that something to do with thin client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To resolve this issue you need to have the DB2 services started as Domain account, not a local account. In order to change the DB2 services to a Domain account do the following:

1.) Go to Start->Control Panel->Administration Tools->Services.

2.) Find the DB2-0 process right click on it and pick "Properties".

3.) Pick the "Log On" tab.

4.) Then choose "This account" radial button, then "Browse".

5.) A window will pop up called Select User click the Advanced button, then click "Find Now".

6.) A list of all users on the machine will be shown, choose the domain user and select "OK".

7.) To save the change click "Apply" then "OK".

8.) Restart the service/instance.
```

Comment: Please also cite/reference original material.

Comment: @Er.NikhilAgrawal not able to select. by default it is "local system account". Other radio button for "this account" is disabled

Answer (score 3):

As the above answer didn't seem to work for me, I'm adding my solution. (command line only) [**windows**]

I simply launched `db2cmd` as the db2admin user (default). 
To achieve this, execute the following command in command prompt:

`runas /noprofile /user:db2admin db2cmd`

This will launch a new cmd window logged in as the admin user. You can now execute any `db2` commands from this window.